# light painting in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I accomplish light painting like [image] 
in Photoshop?  Is there a font I can use?  I couldn't find any great tutorials on it.  Also, note that  I don't own a wacom.

Any help to accomplish this effect in Photoshop is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is quite easy to do with the help of Photoshop or illustrator,you can follow the first tutorial to do the same(it is much similar to your effect), just change your background image.its all about using maximum glow.

- [Lighting shutter text effect](http://www.icanbecreative.com/lighting-shutter-text-effect-tutorial.html)
- [Glowing text effect](http://www.icanbecreative.com/glowing-hello-text-effect-in-photoshop.html)
- [Photoshop text light and glow effect](http://www.google.co.in/#q=light+and+glow+text++effect+photoshop&hl=en&prmd=ivns&ei=JRxbTvLFFcarrAeo16TXCg&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=fb14f34d6fd262fe&biw=1152&bih=692)

Answer (score 2):

For the "handwritten feel" you can write it on a piece of paper, scan it and then overlay it with pen tool in either photoshop or illustrator. Then stroke the path you created with the pen tool and add some maximum glow. Sounds simple but it is very time consuming, well worth it for the effect though.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tutorials-effects/glowing-light-painting-effect/?

First link in google for "light painting effect photoshop"!